How can I debug Python code in the VS Code IDE when using pipx
I did a Sequoia Mac OS update yesterday.
It seems to have hosed my Python dev environment (miniconda, activate command for virtual env in VS Code etc)
Python3.12.6 is what I have now. The latest build - via brew.
I have documented my disillusionment here.
Can someone tell me how I can configure VS Code to be able to debug Python now this is foisted upon me?

Right.
I think Sequouia is as much to blame for this as anything.
Homebrew had been installed for some stuff I do with chess apps I have installed.
Somehow Python now defaulted to the brew instead of miniconda Python interpreter.
I found a video from Jeff Heaton on Youtube I had followed partially and recapped part of his instructions relating to miniforge3.
I found a more up to date link for miniforge3 for the ARM architecture here
I reinstalled miniforge 3 with:
chmod +x Miniforge3-MacOSX-arm64-2.sh 
sh ~/Downloads/Miniforge3-MacOSX-arm64-2.sh

Then I could use regular old pip and my environments again.
Screw pipx. It's an abomination somehow baked into the brew version of Python!
